# html in textview android studio

Tags: android, html

I have textview in which i want to display html which i get from a server so i use like this

```
  Spanned html = Html.fromHtml(content.toString(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT);
```

but it did not display well because the span did not remove the white spaces, so i tried this

```
 int i = html.length();
 while(--i >= 0) {
    char test = html.charAt(i);
    if (test != 0 && !Character.isWhitespace(test)){
       break;
    }
 }
```

and this

```
 CharSequence sub = (html.subSequence(0, descriptionWithOutExtraSpace.length()))
```

and this

```
 String withSpace = html.toString();
 String descriptionWithOutExtraSpace = new String(html.toString()).trim();
```

but all came to the same part that the spaces is removed but it isn't html any more and for example a url is not linked any more
some one have any recommendation for me?

Answer (score -1):

in the and i did it like this

```
Spanned html = Html.fromHtml(content.toString(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT);
String descriptionWithOutExtraSpace = new String(html.toString()).trim();
CharSequence sub = (html.subSequence(0, descriptionWithOutExtraSpace.length()));

holder.binding.contentView.setText(sub);}
```